# iOS: process GUI related events

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, ios7

How to process GUI events like those sent by `reloadData` to a `UITableView` in iOS manually by calling a function/method?

I am using `CoreBluetooth` being peripheral and central at the same time and when receiving information it is needed to update UI. Manually created dispatch queues are used for those.
I assume events from the bluetooth stack prevail in the main events queue so the UI is updated very rarely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what your question is asking but if it is how to update your UI upon the event of new peripherals being discovered ect.

I have built a block based Core Bluetooth manager that I will be open sourcing soon. I scan for peripherals and then update the table view from inside a block that is called once a peripheral is discovered.

If you don't call it on the main thread there is a long delay in this updating the UI.

Simply perform the `reloadData` method on the main thread like so.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Depending on where you are calling it you might not need to make a weak instance of self and may call `[self.tableView reloadData];` instead.

Comment: @user2496553 I have now released the 1st part of my Core Bluetooth Manager. V1.0 only has the Central manager part for now, but the Peripheral Manager part is in development.

You can download it at https://github.com/steprescott/SCPCoreBluetoothManager